# Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted during importing .bas file from specified location

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I am Obtaining run time 1004 error during importing module from one workbook to another workbook in excel using vba code

```
Sub importModuleBas()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim strTemp As String
 sPath = "D:\Users\dheeraj.kumar\Desktop\New folder\"
 sourseFile = sPath & "Projec.xlsm"
 strTemp = sPath & "TransModule.bas"
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sourseFile )
 wb.Activate
 wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import (strTemp)
 Kill (strTemp)
 wb.Close
 End Sub
```

Comment: check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905164

Comment: I have already checked but not get appropriate answer.Please if you have idea then help me.

Comment: It appears you have posted [the exact same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1160223/run-time-error-1004-during-importing-module) under a different account, a practice which is discouraged at SuperUser. You can merge the accounts [here](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that Excel's Trust Center options allow for programmatic access to the VBE/VbProject, and that *both* workbooks are trusted for Macro execution.

See MS KB Article 282830 [Programmatic access to Office VBA project is denied](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/282830)